# emulador android error :app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').- In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices'

Tags: ionic, cordova, google-api, build.gradle, build

hace varios dias vengo arrastrando este problema, no se que mas hacer realmente, intente desinstalando el plugin, cambiandole toda la configuracion(app/platfroms/android/cordova-support-google-service) y no logro resolver, no si alguien se topo alguna vez con este problema.

todo sucede cuando quiero compilar.

**ionic cordova build android --release --verbose**

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.




️* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'intermediateDir' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputDirectory.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'intermediateDir'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'intermediateDir'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'moduleGroup' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'moduleGroup'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'moduleGroup'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'moduleGroupFirebase' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'moduleGroupFirebase'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'moduleGroupFirebase'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'moduleVersion' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'moduleVersion'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'moduleVersion'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageName' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'packageName'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'packageName'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
```

entiendo claramente que es un problema de versiones, pero no encuentro bien en donde seria dicho problema.
**mi ionic info**

```
Ionic:
   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.11.0
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.4
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3
Cordova:
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 10.1.2
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 26 other plugins)
System:
   NodeJS : v14.19.1 (/home/guidogagliardini/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.16
   OS     : Linux 5.13
```

**gradle -v**

---

### Gradle 7.4.2

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          1.8.0_312 (Private Build 25.312-b07)
OS:           Linux 5.13.0-44-generic amd64

Comment: También tengo este mismo problema, pudiste encontrar alguna solución?

Comment: @Dacosta, fue un trabajo duro pero tuve que remover plugin por plugin, y ver  que version iba para mi version de ionic. Los plugins de Google, siempre se estan actualizando y muchas veces quedan viejos, pero si tengo que responder tu pregunta concreta, NO. a ese error no le encontre solucion, borrar todo y empezar de 0, es una solucion, no se si la mejor, pero fue lo que me sirvio. Abrazos!!

Comment: @GuidoGagliardini me alegra que encontraras una solución. Por favor, publica una respuesta con detalles sobre lo que hiciste para que sirva de ayuda a otros usuarios con problemas similares. Lee [answer] para más información.